# Composer - installing packages in parent folder path not a new folder

Tags: php, dependency-management, composer-php

Whenever I do `composer create-project slim/slim` or `composer require slim/slim` + `composer update` composer uploads the project files into a new directory within my already parent project directory so I end up with

myProject -> slim -> my project files here.

What I am trying to do is

myProject -> my project files here

This behavior happens for most frameworks I try to install via composer. I can't move the files that are in the newly created directory into the parent because that messes up the autoloading plus its a headache. I have to work from within a parent myProject dir sometimes because I like to clone git repos and use composer within them.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what file layout you actually want, but here is what I got:

```
mkdir projectDir
cd projectDir
```

That is your empty directory to be filled.

```
composer require slim/slim "2.3.*"
```

That adds the slim framework to your empty directory, i.e. it adds a newly created composer.json file, adds that requirement as well, and installs it.

At this point this directory looks pretty much exactly like your `myProject -> my project files here`.

Comment: The directory after that workflow you did actually looks like this myProject -> vendor -> slim -> files

Comment: Anyway to make it MyProject -> files and still have the vendor/autoload.php work?

Comment: Exactly, but your files do not have to go into `vendor/slim/slim`, or do they? That would be unusual, and it isn't mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.slimframework.com/). All you have to do is include the `vendor/autoload.php` in your code, usually early in the bootstrap.

Comment: no no, I DONT want the files to go into MyProject/vendor/slim/ :) That is what I am trying to avoid. So after doing a composer install and after it stubbornly puts them in vendor/slim, I have to go and manually take the files out and place them in Myproject directory which breaks the autoloading because I can no longer use classes.

Comment: Why do you want to change the location of the Slim files? You don't have to, all you have to do is call the autoloader file pretty close to the start of your first PHP script to make all classes available.

Comment: I do have to change the slim file directory because I care about the architecture of my project. There are other things for me to worry about besides composer's stubborn autoloader.

Comment: So you want to fork the Slim project and maintain it independently? Then you actually should use git to clone the source and go on from there: `git clone https://github.com/codeguy/Slim myProjectFiles` But if you care about the architecture, and do want to benefit from any updates to Slim, you'd better just create your own classes that either extend a Slim class, or encapsulate it. And then it again does not matter where the Slim classes are located, because you only need them get loaded. I haven't really understood what your problem is, but I guess Composer shouldn't be used to solve it.

Comment: The Problem: Dictate where composer uploads dependencies. It doesn't really get any more clearer than that.

Composer should allow its users to dictate the path to where it uploads files and folders. I find this to be a reasonable use case. Just as much as I expect a binary installer to allow me dictate the install path and have it still register the correct path vars in the windows registry without any problems. Composer is lacking, seems as simple as that to me.

Comment: You can define a directory where composer add all required packages to. Default is `vendor`, and this can be changed in your `composer.json` file [config/vendor-dir](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#config). But you cannot change the structure inside this directory. If you include Slim, it MUST be in a directory `vendor/slim/slim` because only that way can it coexists with any other package from the vendor "slim" or any other package.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to generate this structure: *myProject -> my project files*, pass the desired directory to composer and It will generate it.

```
composer require slim/slim "2.3.*" myProject
```